# Отслеживание использования mail() в php

Tags: email, php

Как отследить, кто пользуется функцией mail() в php 5? Есть подозрение, что через нее расслылается спам. Как отследить местоположение скрипта с рассылкой или ограничить доступ к почтовым функциям? Веб сервер Apache.

Поиск "mail(" по коду выдает слишком много результатов.

Answer (score 1):

[mail()](http://php.net/manual/ru/mail.configuration.php) добавляет в письма служебный заголовок `X-PHP-Originating-Script` в котором указывается какой скрипт отправил письмо. Его добавление переключается опцией php `mail.add_x_header` (можно задать в php.ini или через .htaccess например). Документация рулит (: